# Pull request git

Tags: git, github

После последнего pull'a с гитхаба выскочило из головы создать новую ветку для дальнейшей работы и все коммиты делались в мастер.

Сейчас хочу вновь залить проект на гитхаб для проверки и создать pull request.

Возможен ли такой путь:

- создаю ветку branch1 (так понимаю она будет содержать инфу с последнего коммита мастера)
- ее пушу на гитхаб
- создаю PR между реповским мастером и только что залитой веткой branch1

Изменения будут видны?

Comment: git checkout -b, потом дропнуть локальный мастер и выкачать заново - не вариант?

Comment: придется же потом вручную правки вносить, не?

Comment: Не понял. Это же создание новой ветви из текущего коммита.

Comment: логически - впринципе вариант))..просто не знал, что можно дропнуть  локальный мастер, а потом запулить с репо старый. а мой ваирант вообще не годится? разве в PR сравнивается не реповский мастер с запушенной веткой?

Comment: Не знаю... Может и так.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно оставить на текущем месте (с изменениями) новую ветку:

```
git checkout -b branch1
```

...и запушить **только её**.

```
git push -u origin branch1
```

Да, изменения будут видны, если на сервере старый `master`.
На этом этапе уже можно делать pull request.

---

Но локальный `master` при этом стоит откатить до состояния на сервере, чтобы избежать сюрпризов при дальнейшей работе. Это можно сделать в любой момент, но лучше всего после отправки `branch1` на сервер, чтобы уж точно ничего не потерять.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Последняя команда принудительно вешает ветку `master` в указанную точку (`origin/master`). В таком виде она относительно безопасна, т. к. история не переписывается, а чуть-чуть перемещается в прошлое.

Но в общем случае ею можно легко наделать дел и потерять новые коммиты. Поэтому хорошая привычка оставлять на месте, с которого ветка снимается, другую, запасную ветку. Здесь это уже сделано: как раз там лежит `branch1`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.. т.е. RP возьмет для сравнения именно мастер из репо? и ветку branch1. после создания PR смогу откатить локальный мастер до серверного.. после в RP смерджить master и branch, а после уже запулить все обратно на локальную машину?

Comment: @rostov-7 вы делаете PR на сервере. Берёте одну серверную ветку и предлагаете в другую. Ваши локальные ветки могут жить своей жизнью. Откатить локальный `master` до серверного состояния можно когда угодно.

Answer (score 3):

Можно спрятать локальные изменения, спулиться, а потом их смерджить обратно

```
git reset --soft commit_name
git stash
git pull --ff-only origin master
git stash apply

// тут могут предложить смерджиться, если автомердж не прошел.
```

после этого можно продолжать разработку в актуальном мастере